# Installing phonegap in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cordova

I want to create phonegap application for iPhone/iPad. I checked their website but it says that it supports only xcode 4.3. I think that there will be a way to install lower versions of phonegap like 1.5 or something in xcode 4.2. But I din find any proper documentation for the same in their website (for xcode 4.2). Can anybody help me with the issue.

I can't update to xcode 4.2 as I am using snow leaprd and I don't want to update to lion.

Comment: download the 1.5 version of phonegap, here is a link from there site [a link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/zipball/1.5.0).

Comment: Yeah.. I saw that.. but there are no istructions for it right? The instructions given are for xcode 4.3. I can't figure out somethings like how to install command line tools etc..

Comment: Please find how to install it on this [a link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-xcode-for-ios.html)

Comment: Yeah. thanks Scar. It worked. Command line tools etc.. where not even required for installing phonegap v1.5. Thanks Scar.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329871/is-it-possible-to-use-phonegap-2-2-0-with-xcode-4-2-1/17668069#17668069).

You can just fix the compile errors. I documented the process [here](http://programming.mvergel.com/2013/07/xcode-42-and-phonegap-cordova-and.html). It works with the basic app, not sure if you add more complex codes.