# Is it possible to use phonegap 2.2.0 with Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to use phonegap 2.2.0 with Xcode 4.2.1? I had follow the instruction from phone gap site, but xcode prompt me many error message such like "No known class method found for selector "createBackupInfoWithCloudBackup". Beside that, libCordova.a shown in red font in the "Link Binary With Libraries". I had change all the architecture to armv7. But, problem still exist. Anyone can help/advice me?

Comment: Is there any reason not to upgrade to the latest version of xcode? (currently 4.5.2)

Comment: If you're stuck in Snow Leopard, you're also stuck with XCode 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You can just fix the compile errors. Was able to make it work with Phonegap / Cordova 2.9 and XCode 4.2 (with iOS SDK 5) and Snow Leopard. I documented the process [here](http://programming.mvergel.com/2013/07/xcode-42-and-phonegap-cordova-and.html).